# How to create a loop for each row in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables (`Users`, `CourseUsers` and `Courses` which represent the courses assigned to a single user).

I would like to create a procedure which, as soon as I create a new course, will assign this course to every user. What I see I need here is a **For each** loop to iterate through every user inserting a new row in `CourseUsers` table

How do I create a loop in SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a loop.

```
DECLARE @CourseId INT;

INSERT INTO Courses(Name) VALUES('Some Course');

SET @CourseId  = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO CourseUsers(UserId, CourseId)
SELECT UserId, @CourseId
FROM Users;
```

Comment: and how do I repeat it for every UserId I have?

Comment: @RodrigoAlves That will insert 1 row per user. Therefore its already doing the repeating that you are referring to.

Comment: @RodrigoAlves - You don't need to. The `SELECT FROM Users` does that.

Comment: uhhh! That's great! Well, I also have to insert more data other than the data in users table (such as current datetime). Where do I put it in my SQL Statement

Comment: @Rodrigo Alves, think of it this way: the `INSERT INTO CourseUsers...` will insert one row for every row returned by the query: `SELECT UserId, @CourseId FROM Users;` this is generally called an INSERT-SELECT statement.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you don't.

You can issue an insert statement that will insert a new row in that CourseUsers table for every User:

```
INSERT INTO CourseUsers(CourseId, UserId)
SELECT @CourseId, UserId
FROM Users
```

SQL is a set-based language: usually you can work on an entire set of data, without the need for loops.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop for doing this.

You can use an `INSERT` [trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) and access the [`INSERTED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) logical table, operating on the results of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
INSERT INTO CourseUsers (CourseID,UserID)
SELECT 7, UserID FROM Users
```

Where 7 is your course id (this would obviously change from course to course!).